# Android: How to specify the opacity of a <layer-list>?

Tags: android, android-layout, opacity, layer-list

I want my LayerList to have an opacity of 80 so I wrote:

```
<layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:opacity="80">
```

But I get:

```
Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'opacity' with value '80')
```

How can I specify the opacity?

Comment: If you can do it that way - what I'm not sure for layer-list. This will be called android:alpha

Answer (score -1, accepted):

android:opacity supports only translucent|opaque|transparent values in layer-list.

By the way what is your requirement?

Updated-Answer:
To set opacity/less-visible as 80%, you need to set to your view

`android:alpha="0.8"`

Comment: Requirement: make the image less visible (it is an image in the background, just for style)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Sorry didn't get back to you.                                        As per my understanding, you are using the layerList that you have created as a background drawable in an ImageView or some other view using @drawable/layer_list. To set opacity/ image less visible as 80%, you need to set `android:alpha="0.8"`

Comment: (I switched to another solution meanwhile, so I won't test this soon, but I accept as it is the only answer)

Answer (score 1):

To give a translucent effect, say 50% opacity, use:

`Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);

d.setAlpha(130);

mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);`

'130' can be changed (0-255) to acheive desired opacity.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question asks about setting the opacity of individual items inside a `<layer-list>`, and not the whole image programmatically.

If you know the color already, Use a combine hex RGBA code, for e.g. :

`<solid android:color="#80FF0000" />`

Sets the color to red (0xFF0000) with 0x80 opacity.

Same thing applies to few other items. e.g. stroke

`<stroke android:color="#6000FF00" android:width="20dp" />`

This creates a 20dp thick green stroke of 0x60 opacity.

Futher, if you want to do it pro grammatically, i.e. modify the alpha of a specific item and not the whole drawable, use a new resource id (android:id="@+id/...") for the item and access it . I haven't happened to verify this part though.